# What did the "cloud of positive charge" consist of in the Plum Pudding atomic model?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, atomic-physics, history

Did this cloud have mass? Was it just an electric field or was it a particle, or something else? If it was an electric field, how was it created and how did it maintain its form? From my understanding, an electric field arises between spatially separated and oppositely charged objects. If the cloud was indeed labelled an electric field in the model, where were those objects? Or was the understanding of electric fields different back then?

Comment: Really a History of Science Stack Exchange question?

Comment: @Farcher I was wondering about that, and I might ask the mods to migrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did this cloud have mass?

It would have to: electrons have a very small mass, so that if we add all the masses of the electrons in a piece of material, we'd underestimate the total mass of the piece by several orders of magnitude. Thus, something has to add to yield the actual mass, and this cloud is a natural candidate within this theory.

> Was it just an electric field or was it a particle, or something else?

No, it was supposed to be a volume of charge. Maybe a particle, maybe a multitude of particles—the theory just didn't consider what it actually was. Just "a sphere of uniform positive electrification". You can read the actual article by J.J.Thomson in ref. 1 below.

The first positively-charged particles discovered were alpha particles, and although they were discovered in 1899, before the plum pudding model of 1904, they were not even known to be ions of helium until 1907. So it's unlikely that someone could identify the nature of the positive charge proposed by Thomson's theory.

---

#### References

1. Thomson, J. J. (March 1904). ["On the Structure of the Atom: an Investigation of the Stability and Periods of Oscillation of a number of Corpuscles arranged at equal intervals around the Circumference of a Circle; with Application of the Results to the Theory of Atomic Structure"](https://zenodo.org/record/1430726/files/article.pdf). Philosophical Magazine. Sixth. 7 (39): 237–265. [doi:10.1080/14786440409463107](https://doi.org/10.1080%2F14786440409463107).

Comment: So Thomson himself never elaborated or speculated upon the cause or content of the cloud? And up until the model's replacement, was there ever a time when scientists accepted some kind of leading explanation of the cloud's content/cause?

Comment: @user110391 The model addressed experimental data.  I'm not sure what you conceptualize as a "cause". The electron was a known thing with known properties, but what "causes" an electron to exist? Why shouldn't clouds of positive charge exist?

Comment: @JohnDoty Well, that would depend on whether the cloud was said to be a fundamental particle/object, or not. If the latter, then it needs a cause. Like, I can ask you what the cause of a proton is, and what is consists of. But for an electron, I can't, because that's an elementary particle. If they said that the cloud was just a fundamental part of reality, then the cause would be "because it just exists", but I was wondering if they maybe didn't think it was an elementary particle, but rather a composite particle. And in that case, I wondered what their explanation for it was.

Comment: @user110391 don't forget the historical context. There was no concept of an elementary or composite particle. The atom was a mystery back then, and Thomson's model is one of the earliest attempts to describe it. Even (free) electrons were first discovered as some kind of "rays" ([cathode rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_rays)), and only then found to be something particle-like. And only with quantum mechanics and nuclear physics did the concept of composite particles appear (and elementary particle as the opposite).

Comment: @Ruslan Okay so this was basically so early that no attempt was made to, nor expectation held for, the explanation of what the cloud was made of and how it came to be? In other words, my mistake here is thinking, "if I just supposed some phenomenon was caused by a cloud of positive electrification (or another equivalently foreign idea), then people would demand an explanation for how this came to be." And perhaps I'm right in that, but only because we know so much nowadays that an unexplainable object is unlikely. But back then they knew so much less, so no explanation was understandable?

Comment: _"so no explanation was understandable"_ — I'd say no explanation was required right then. The people were trying to come up with a model that works. Remember the Bohr's model: the electron was postulated to not radiate on particular orbits. "Why doesn't it radiate?" — would be anyone's question. But it was not time for detalization, it was time for generating ideas to explain what was already known—and testing them. And Thomson's model failed some tests (Rutherford's, in particular), which made the question about the nature of the positive cloud of charge irrelevant.

Answer (score -3):

See my explanation here: arxiv.org/abs/0806.2635 and here: vladimirkalitvianski.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/… Briefly, it is quantum mechanical smearing that forms charged clouds in the elastic picture.

I cite: "By the way, in a solid state the positive charge “clouds” are rather large and comparable with the lattice step. So in elastic picture the positive charge in a solid is distributed as in a “plum pudding” model! And in molecules too – the positive charge clouds are very large, but nobody pictures them either!"